# Are there "draw split" keys for other split shapes besides the rectangle split?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

The TikZ rectangle shape has a draw split key "/pgf/rectangle split draw splits=boolean" but in the TikZ manual there is no reference of similar keys for the: circle split, ellipse slipt, circle solidus, etc... By any chance, do similar key exist? If no, any suggestions on how to create them? That is how can we **suppress** the split line? Is the an equivalent of **rectangle split draw splits=false** for the other shapes? If not, any suggestions on how to implement it?

The MWE (circle split draw split=false also does not work but for the rectangle as in the manual it does work)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,automata,trees,
 positioning,shadows,matrix,arrows,shapes.geometric,shapes.multipart,trees,
 calc,  fit,decorations.pathmorphing}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [circle split, circle split draw splits=false]
  {test 1  \nodepart{lower} test 2};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split draw splits=false]
  {test 1  \nodepart{two} test 2};
 \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: No reference? Really? Section 67.6 'Shapes with Multiple Text Parts'. First shape: `circle split`. Second: `circle solidus`. Next shape: `ellipse split`. (Page 731 of the 3.0 manual.)

Comment: @cfr Yes. Really, I read all these pages before posting the question. The **rectangle slip draw splits=false** works but if you try **circle split draw splits=false** or **circle split draw splits=false** pgf says that it does not know the key and is ignoring it.

Comment: @cfr The question is not about split shapes in general  but about a **key** that allow the **split line** to be drawn (or not, what is what I am looking for)

Comment: @PaulGessler: yes of course, adding MWE so people are not so fast to throw the first stone...

Comment: Well if you provided an MWE or had explained at all, your question might have been somewhat less muddied. I suggest that you edit your title as well as your question body since the obvious answer to that is still 'yes, and they are well documented'.

Comment: @cfr: Thanks for the suggestion but the title is correct. I suspect you maybe thinking about something else? My question is about about an specific key with this name. See page 736 of the manual **rectangle split draw splits**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this, some hacking is required. Unfortunately, due to some inconsistencies in the implementation between the `circle split` and the `ellipse split` shapes different methods must be used for both.

If hacking is not desirable, then it might worth considering that a `circle split` shape with out the "split" drawn is just a `circle` shape with text stacked vertically inside (with adjustments for spacing to match the separation of the node parts).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\makeatletter
\pgfutil@namelet{pgf@sh@fbg@circle split@original}{pgf@sh@fbg@circle split}%
\newif\ifpgfshapecirclesplitdrawsplits
\pgfshapecirclesplitdrawsplitstrue
\pgfkeys{%
  /pgf/circle split draw splits/.is if=pgfshapecirclesplitdrawsplits
}
\def\pgf@sm@shape@name{circle split}
\pgf@sh@beforebgpath{%
  \ifpgfshapecirclesplitdrawsplits%
    \csname pgf@sh@fbg@circle split@original\endcsname%
  \fi
}


\newif\ifpgfshapeellipsesplitdrawsplits
\pgfshapeellipsesplitdrawsplitstrue
\pgfkeys{%
  /pgf/ellipse split draw splits/.is if=pgfshapeellipsesplitdrawsplits
}
\def\pgf@sm@shape@name{ellipse split}
\pgf@sh@bgpath{%
  \radii%
    \pgfmathaddtolength\pgf@x{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
    \pgfmathaddtolength\pgf@y{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \pgfutil@tempdima\pgf@x%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb\pgf@y%
  \pgfpathellipse{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpoint{\the\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\the\pgfutil@tempdimb}}%
  \ifpgfshapeellipsesplitdrawsplits
      \pgfpathmoveto{\centerpoint\advance\pgf@x-\pgfutil@tempdima}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\centerpoint\advance\pgf@x\pgfutil@tempdima}%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle split,draw] 
  at (0,0) {A \nodepart{lower} B};
\node [circle split,draw,circle split draw splits=false] 
  at (2,0) {C \nodepart{lower} D};

\node [ellipse split,draw] 
  at (0,2) {ABCD \nodepart{lower} EFGH};
\node [ellipse split,draw,ellipse split draw splits=false] 
  at (2,2) {IJKL \nodepart{lower} MNOP};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]